# Get IP address of AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache

I have a Redis cluster in AWS ElastiCache

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "custom-redis-cluster" {
...
}
```

I want to access the IP of all of it' clusters.
I have tried using `dns_a_record_set` to manually get the IP address from the DNS name
but it's not working as well.

```
data "dns_a_record_set" "esg-redis-data" {
  host = "custom-redis-cluster.abcd1e.clustercfg.use2.cache.amazonaws.com"
}

variable "custom-redis-cluster-addrs" {
  type = list(string)
  value = data.dns_a_record_set.custom-redis-cluster.addrs
}
```

Error

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on endpoint.services.tf line 37, in variable "custom-redis-cluster-addrs":
  37:   value = data.dns_a_record_set.custom-redis-cluster.addrs
```

How should I fetch the IP address of all the Redis clusters from Terraform?

Is there a way to fetch the Redis clusters DNS name dynamically instead of hard coding?

Comment: "but it's not working as well" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors, timeouts?

Comment: @Marcin Thank you for the comment, I have added the error with dns_a_record_set

Comment: What are you trying to do with `variable "custom-redis-cluster-addrs"`?

Comment: I am trying to add them to the target group of the network load balancer, it only takes IP. In clustered mode Redis can have more than one depending on shard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can't use variables**  to define `custom-redis-cluster-addrs` variable.
But you can create a `local`:

```
locals {
    custom-redis-cluster-addrs = data.dns_a_record_set.custom-redis-cluster.addrs
}
```

and use it as `local.custom-redis-cluster-addrs` where you need it.

Comment: Thanks, it works just one more thing. Is there a way to dynamically fetch the DNS name of the Redis cluster?

Comment: @AbhishekPatil There is `aws_elasticache_cluster` data source that will return dns for an existing cluster.